# Check equality in 'else' in 'if - else' statement

Tags: javascript

Say we have such code (js):

```
/**
 * @param  {String} type Could be only 'high' or 'low'
 * @return {String}
 */
function getSome(type) {
    if (type == 'high') {
        return 'This is high';
    } else if (type == 'low') {
        return 'This is low';
    }
}
```

If this variant preferable than this (I do not include comments; they are the same)?:

```
function getSome(type) {
    if (type == 'high') {
        return 'This is high';
    } else {
        return 'This is low';
    }
}
```

I had got the similar situations many times. Usually I did not think about the best variant and wrote what came the first. But now I want to decide what variant to use in the future.

The final question. If I need to check equality of a variable in `else` if a variable could have only two values and the first value was given in `if` statement? I also want to know how using function comments could affect the answer.

Comment: I'm not really following you. If you **know** for certain that only two different values can be passed to that function then the second version is fine. If you can't make any guarantees about that (and we rarely can) it's better to do the first and throw an error in a final `else` case.

Comment: Well, both of these examples have different behavior. You have to choose the one that produces the result you want.

Comment: Ultimately comments don't affect the actual code paths taken, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: Both version are not the same, the first will return `undefined` (if not high or low), the second will default to low

Comment: About comments -- they are not here to decide which code style you will use. Second is definitely better and you should prefer it (of course, add another branch where type is neither "high" or "low". Also, this type of comment is not really helpful. Since it's JS you should explain better what type is (I guess this is just a simple example, but still)

Comment: @SvenVidak the second one is only better if you need to pay by the byte or something. The first implementation is superior in every single way aside from being _slightly_ longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use an object as grouping for the two values. For not known type, the function returns undefined, or any other default value.

```
function getSome(type) {
    return { high: 'This is high', low: 'This is low'}[type];
}
```

With default

```
function getSome(type) {
    return { high: 'This is high', low: 'This is low'}[type] || 'type not known.';
}
```

Comment: This inspire me to see another solution: using ternary operations (in two places). Becides it is harder to read it is still longer than your way.

Answer (score 8):

If only the values `high` and `low` are valid, consider a third option:

```
function getSome(type) {
    if (type === 'high') {
        return 'This is high';
    } else if (type === 'low') {
        return 'This is low';
    } else {
        throw new Error(type + ' is invalid');
    }
}
```

**Fail fast.** This may help you find bugs a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

It will be much more convenient to use `switch` operator, especially if you have more possible values:

```
function getSome(type) {

    switch(type){

         case 'hight':
             return 'This is a high';
             break;
         case 'low':
             return 'This is a low';
             break;
         case 'third':
             return 'This is a third';
             break;
         default:
             throw new Error(type + ' is invalid.');
             break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple of notes: 1) You don't need `break` after `return` since it will never hit the `break`. 2) I personally think `switch` statements are overkill when you're only expecting 2 values, as OP indicated. Compare how much code you have to read for your solution vs. theirs.

Comment: 2. > especially if you have more possible values

Comment: Those are your opinions, I have mine.

Comment: To me, it looks as weird as having two return statements in a row.